# CefSharp browser capture screenshot

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, cefsharp

Can you help me? I'm trying take a screenshot of the page, but I'm only capturing a blank page instead.
Here is my code:

```
browser2 = new CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser("https://iqoption.com/pt/login")
{

    Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
    Size = new Size(600, 600),
        Location = new Point(200, 200)
};
this.panel3.Controls.Add(browser2);
```

And here is how I'm printing the page:

```
void print()
{
    int scrollWidth = 0;
    int scrollHeight = 0;

    scrollHeight = browser2.Height;
    scrollWidth = browser2.Width;
    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(scrollWidth, scrollHeight);

    browser2.DrawToBitmap(bm, new Rectangle(0, 0, bm.Width, bm.Height));
    bm.Save(@"test.png", ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

As I have said, no errors, just blank page being saved. Can you help me? Note that `print()` is being called after 20 seconds, so there is not risk of "page isn't fully loaded".

Thank you.

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2286

Comment: This seems to be a little different from my situation.

Comment: Details of using `BitBlt` to take a screenshot are listed in the original issue. Potential problems this method with newer versions of `Chromium`. `DrawToBitmap` is not supported as the `ChromiumWebBrowser` is really a host for the native `Win32` Chromium implementation.

Comment: If you can find a way to make `DrawToBitmap` work then your welcome to submit a `PR`.

Comment: You should be able to take a screenshot via Remote Debugging using something like `PuppateerSharp`. See https://gist.github.com/amaitland/52831ce341f65554540d91eba951bebe for an old example, API may have changed. Assumes you've enabled remote debugging on 8088 https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/81/CefSharp.Example/CefExample.cs#L63